# start a jquery function over

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to start a function over, based on an `if` statement, in JQuery or Javascript?  Something like how `return functionname();` is to PHP?

For example

```
function awesomestuff {
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
   if(x == 1) { //start function over }
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
}
```

I imagine this can be accomplished with an `if/else` statement, but if the function gets pretty big, it can get pretty messy.

Comment: Just call the function again: `return awesomestuff()`. Beware of infinite recursion.

Comment: Do you want to do the stuff in the second half of the function more than once?

Comment: Hi RCNeil, It depends if you want to use recursion or not (which has the function call itself). Using recursion or not can change the functionality a lot. If you **do not** want the function to call itself and **all code** after the if (x == 1), use a loop. If you do want that code called every time, recursion should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your supplied PHP example of returning the functionname() in JS too, with the exactly same syntax...

Comment: this is the best answer. did he even try it??

Comment: I did not.  No.  I'm a whore for rep I guess.  I didn't see this question on here, so it doesn't hurt right?

Comment: I am sure he did not, else he would not have asked.

Comment: i meant did you even try just doing what you do in php. you wrote the answer to your question in your question.

Comment: I'd like to add a delay as well, so would I use `setTimeout()` in that case?

Comment: Yes, but you can not return that (you can but it does not contain the return value)

Comment: Ah true. Plus it seems that the initial `setInterval()` timing and the delay I put on `setTimeout` conflict with one another.  I will find another method.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
function awesomestuff() {
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
   if(x == 1) { awesomestuff(); }
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are asking for a recursion which can be just done by calling the function again inside the condition,

```
//Note you were missing ()
function awesomestuff () {
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
   if(x == 1) { 
      //start function over 
      awesomestuff ();
   }
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't generate the same end result, as the rest of the function (after the recursion) will execute for each recursion, which could lead to unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you actually want to do --

```
function awesomestuff {
    x = 1;
    while (x==1) {
       //do stuff;
       //do stuff;
    }
    //do stuff;
    //do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a do while loop ?

```
function awesomestuff {
   do {
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
   while(x == 1);// { //start function over }
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function awesomestuff () {
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
   if(x == 1) { 
       //start function over
       awesomestuff();

       // do not continue this execution
       // remove this if you still want to do the "do stuff" below
       return;
   }
   //do stuff;
   //do stuff;
}
```

Comment: Return in your function will never be reach as you recall the same exact function in infinite loop. Btw, should be function awesomestuff (){...} but just a typo.

Comment: @roasted thanks, i knew that syntax looked fishy when i copied it from the question. as for the return statement, it will always be executed as the recursion unpacks itself, and i assume the OP is decrementing the `x` variable somewhere.